# Hashing numbers to the intervals that contain them

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hash

Suppose I have a set of disjoint real intervals, e.g. `{[0,1), [1, 5], [7.5, 9.2]}`. I want to store this information in a data structure that supports the following operation in constant time:

- `find(x):` given a float `x`, this should return the index of the interval containing `x` (or -1 if no such interval exists). For example `find(0.5) -> 0`, `find(8.1) -> 2`, `find(6) -> -1`.

Does such a data structure exist? And if so, does it have a name?

The best that I can come up with is to sort the intervals and implement `find` via binary search, which takes O(log k) for k intervals.

Comment: Although not really an answer, if I recall correctly, the implementers of Gecode went back to a *list* of intervals instead of a binary tree, since it was actually in many cases more efficient. Yes, in terms of time complexity a tree is better. But since the number of intervals was typically quite small, and updating such tree can be cumbersome (if you for example want to construct a *union* with another interval tree), it turned out a list was better.

Comment: Can you assume anything about the intervals? e.g. are they somewhat evenly distributed in the real line?

Comment: Your binary search tree is a good solution if the intervals don't overlap. If they do overlap, then perhaps an [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) would help you.